# What is the correct way to use a headless chrome browser for running Rails system tests in Heroku pipeline

Tags: heroku, capybara, google-chrome-headless, ruby-on-rails-7, web-testing

I have my pipeline setup such that a push to main on my GitHub repository triggers Heroku to pull the latest commit and build a system for test.  The test setup succeeds but the system tests fail immediately failing to find the chrome browser:

-----> Running test command `bin/rails test:system`...
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/webdrivers-5.2.0/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:21:in `location': Failed to determine Chrome binary location. (Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound) from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/webdrivers-5.2.0/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:10:in` version'

here is my app.json:

```
{
    "buildpacks": [
      { "url": "heroku/ruby" },
      { "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver" },
      { "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome" }
    ],

    "environments": {
        "test": {
          "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"],
          "scripts": {
            "test": "bin/rails test:system"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

from the set up log, it looks like the chrome-related buildpacks were loaded:

-----> Fetching heroku/ruby buildpack...
buildpack downloaded
-----> Fetching https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver buildpack...
buildpack downloaded
-----> Fetching https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome buildpack...
buildpack downloaded

I can rn these system tests locally with chrome and headless chrome.  Also, I run system tests via an Action on GitHub with every push to main and this uses headless chrome just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found some [helpful Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci#configure-your-test-environment)

Based on this I created an app.json file:

```
{
"buildpacks": [
  { "url": "heroku/ruby" },
  { "url": "heroku/chromedriver" },
  { "url": "heroku/google-chrome" }
],

"environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"],
      "scripts": {
        "test": "bin/rails test:system"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also added code to my test_helper.rb based on [this advice](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-browser-and-user-acceptance-testing-uat#testing-with-selenium) to point chromedriver to the correct location on the Heroku test environment.
The added code follows the comment: "#this code to provide correct path ...":

```
#test_helper.rb
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

  #This code to provide correct path to the chrome library on heroku test environment
  chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)

  chrome_opts = chrome_bin ? { "chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_bin } } : {}

  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :chrome,
      desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_opts)
    )
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

  # End chrome lib path setup

end
```

As far as I could tell, this code followed the documentation correctly and should have worked for me but it did not and I still received a failure on the Heroku test app saying BrowserNotFound.  I added a statement at the end of test_helper.rb to directly set the path and that solved my problem.  I now have system tests running locally and on a ephemeral test app on Heroku on each push to GitHub main.

Here is my working version of test_helper.rb:

```
    ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

  #This code to provide correct path to the chrome library on heroku test environment
  chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)

  chrome_opts = chrome_bin ? { "chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_bin } } : {}

  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :chrome,
      desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_opts)
    )
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
  if ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM']
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM']
  end
  # End chrome lib path setup

end
```

This seems a bit kludgy but its my first working version!